# Why do I get System.TypeInitializationException while trying to initiaize an object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, initialization

I get an exception while trying to initalize an object. This is the exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in GeneticProcessorGUI.exe
```

This is the call to the function that seems to throw the error:

```
ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS.FitnessAurocCv fitnessCalc =
            new ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS.FitnessAurocCv("localhost", "CP20141118", "CP20141118", "dbo_DataSourceFraud", 10, 5);
```

I tried adding some logs to the function, but it doesn't print any of them, so i think it fails in the call, before it executes any code.

This is the constructor code:

```
 public FitnessAurocCv(string asServerConnectionString, string asDatabaseName, string dataSourceView, string tableName, int numberOfFolds, int foldsToTest)
        {
            _dataSourceView = dataSourceView;
            _tableName = tableName;
            _numberOfFolds = numberOfFolds;
            _foldsToTest = foldsToTest;
            _dataBaseName = asDatabaseName;

            _availableVars = CreateVariablesList();

            _asServer = new Server();

            _log.Debug("Connecting to " + asServerConnectionString);

            _asServer.Connect(asServerConnectionString);

            _asDatabase = _asServer.Databases[asDatabaseName];

            _log.Debug("Connected OK.");

        }
```

What could be causing this? I use the exact same call in another application and it works just fine, i have not found anything useful online, and could really use your help.

Just in case, here is the code of the entire class that causes the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS;

namespace GeneticProcessorGUI
{

    public class Controller
    {

        private GeneticProcessorGUI gpgui;

        public void startGUI(){

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            gpgui = new GeneticProcessorGUI(this);
            Application.Run(gpgui);
        }

        public void ProcessPosibleVariables(string server, string database, string datasourceview, string tablename)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("PPV");
            try
            {
                //ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS.FitnessAurocCv fitnessCalc =
                //new ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS.FitnessAurocCv(server, database, datasourceview, tablename, 10, 5);
                ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS.FitnessAurocCv fitnessCalc =
                new ModelingAutomation.MR.Fitness.SSAS.FitnessAurocCv("localhost", "CP20141118", "CP20141118", "dbo_DataSourceFraud", 10, 5);
                MessageBox.Show("before call");
                Dictionary<string, string> vars = fitnessCalc.CreateVariablesListFromSource();
                MessageBox.Show("" + vars.ToArray().Length);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in vars)
                {
                    // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
                    MessageBox.Show(entry.Value + " , " + entry.Key);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Is `FitnessAurocCv` inheriting/implementing anything?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85247e46-68fa-4bc6-9d18-332e48d170f3/in-english-please-a-first-chance-exception-of-type-systemtypeinitializationexception?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: This exception most commonly caused by failures in static construcot for the type (or initialization of static fields). Without code it is not possible to say for sure... Debug your application and makes sure to understand ALL exceptions that happen.

Comment: You should be able to spot the location of the error if you turn on "Break when an exception is"..."Common Language Runtime Exceptions"..."Thrown" and run the app in the debugger.  To do this, press Ctrl-D, then "E", then check the checkbox in the "Thrown" column in the row "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

Comment: provide the stack trace details.